# Setting the value for setAttribute by looping through an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, attributes

I'm quite new to JavaScript and want to set the attribute of an element with the use of a loop and variables. Run the example below [here](http://js.do/code/arraysetattrib).

```
<h1 id="header">START</h1>

<button onclick="run()">run</button>

<script>
  function run()
  {
    var s, myStringArray = ["red", "blue"];
    for (s of myStringArray)
    {
      document.getElementById("header").setAttribute("style","color:"+s);
    }
  }
</script>
```

This works, but I'd like to have an array with variables containing the complete value for `setAttribute`.

For instance:

```
attribArray = [""style","color:red"", ""style","color:blue""]
```

This is a hypothetical question and the exemplary code doesn't make much sense.

How would I create such an array, so that I can loop through it and use the variable as above, directly in`document.getElementById("header").setAttribute(theVar)`?

Comment: Why are you making the text red and then immediately blue?

Comment: As stated in the OP, this obviously doesn't make sense and this is just an example.

Comment: Then the problem statement doesn't make sense. Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I do not understand comments like these. I just tried to give a simple example of my actual code to simplify the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array of objects:

```js
function run() {
  var myAttributes = [
    { attr: "style", value: "color: red" },
    { attr: "style", value: "color: blue" }
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < myAttributes.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("header").setAttribute(myAttributes[i].attr, myAttributes[i].value);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">START</h1>

<button onclick="run()">run</button>
```

Now, keep in mind that your code and this snippet will update the color of the same element twice, so it is quite pointless. If you want to loop colors, you can do the following:

```js
let current = 0;
function run() {
  var myAttributes = [
    { attr: "style", value: "color: red" },
    { attr: "style", value: "color: blue" },
    { attr: "style", value: "color: yellow" },
    { attr: "style", value: "color: green" }
  ];
  
  document.getElementById("header").setAttribute(myAttributes[current].attr, myAttributes[current].value);
  
  current = current === (myAttributes.length - 1) ? 0 : current + 1;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">START</h1>

<button onclick="run()">run</button>
```

## Bonus: ES6 Syntax

Using ES6 syntax, we can make it look a bit friendlier to the eye:

```
function run() {
    let header = document.getElementById("header");
    const myAttributes = [
        { attr: "style", value: "color: red" },
        { attr: "style", value: "color: blue" }
    ];

    for (let { attr, value } of myAttributes) {
        header.setAttribute(attr, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good! Is there a way to do this with a variable number of elements, for the setAttribute value? For instance `var myAttributes = [""style","color:red"", ""style","color:blue","background-color:black;""]`

Comment: For that case, you can do something like this: `{ attr: "style", value: "color: red; background-color: black;" }`. The value can contain as many styles as you need. Anything else would require additional changes.